# qt/wxwidgets third party components?

Tags: qt, components, wxwidgets

I'm used to working in a Delphi and C# environment which seem to have a rich set of third party components available. I'm currently wanting to do cross-platform programming in C++ using either qt or wxwidgets. Is there a large market for third party components? I was looking at sourceforge and that doesn't seem to show much that is useful (how the hell do you find out what components or features are in a project without downloading the source?). I'm thinking carousel/coverflow components, rich datagrids (like the sort DevExpress provide). Or is this, write your own territory?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of good quality third party Qt libraries, though I don't know of a centralized resource for finding them.

A few places to start looking:

- [http://www.ics.com/products/qt/addons](http://www.ics.com/products/qt/addons/)

  [ICS](http://www.ics.com) provides the
  [QicsTable](http://www.ics.com/products/qt/qicstable/), a high performance
  model-view-delegate table library,
  and resells various libraries by
  KDAB.  (These are all available as a
  free download.)
- http://www.qtcentre.org/contest-first-edition/finalists

  [QtCentre](http://www.qtcentre.org) has an annual
  programming contest which awards
  interesting Qt-based tools and
  libraries.  This year's contest is
  still being judged, but the
  finalists from last year can be seen
  at the above link.  Check out the
  Custom Widget and Helper Library
  categories.

Answer (score 3):

There is a third-party component for Qt - advanced data grid - Qtitan DataGrid. 
In it there are almost all necessary possibilities.

Ultra-fast processing of large data sets
Use of QStyle for rendering objects ensures that the grid blends into the UI design of any application
Two modes of vertical scrolling
Customizable colors of rows and columns
Two integrated table views
Column banding and grouping
Automatic width and height adjustment
Fixed columns
Flexible sorting
Column summaries
Integrated high-performance caching mechanism
Advanced paint engine for faster rendering of UI elements
Cross-platform support
API for external editors

Screenshots about this Grid
http://www.devmachines.com/qtitan_screenshots.php

Answer (score 2):

For a crossplatform GUI development, Qt is the tool you should be looking for. I have used both. Here is what I feel about Qt

Building rich GUI is a piece of cake if you use Qt. It has a loads of GUI capabilities, starting with its Graphics View, OpenGL support, stylesheets that supports css. A mature painting system, Richtext formatting, Integration with Webkit, and I am sure I am missing a lot more here...

Qt has its own build system, qmake which creates platform dependent Makefiles, so no Makefile hassles. Moreover you get a single pro-file which is much easier to manage. For wxWidgets, you will need to create different Makefiles for the various compilers you intent to use.

Other advantages of using Qt over wxWidgets are - the Api is very easy to learn with its intuitive api, superb documentation and tons and tons of examples. This helps you get yourself productive pretty soon and thus getting your product early to marker. BTW Qt is a RAD tool. Moreover, there is a huge user base, and there are forums like QtCentre.org to help you with your questions.
If you are planning to buy commercial license, you get support directly from Qt Software (trolltech).

You would obviously be using Qt's Model View pattern, allowing you to separate your business logic from the presentation tier.  I would suggest that you write to "support at trolltech dot com" or "sales at trolltech dot com" to get more information. You can explain your requirements and they would be able to explain how Qt fits your needs.

You could also download the opensource version and have look at the demos.
Coverflow: http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2007/11/02/pictureflow-on-windows-mobile/ , http://ariya.blogspot.com/2008/03/introducing-photoflow.html

As I said, if its Rich gui you are planning to develop, use Qt.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the ones by ICS and at QtCentre the [Qt-apps](http://www.qt-apps.org/index.php?xcontentmode=4298) website has some open source widgets/components for Qt.

Answer (score 1):

For wxWidgets you have [wxCode](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/) which has quite a few things although not all the existing third party components (including a few very useful ones) are available from there.

Answer (score 1):

Good quality components for Qt can be found here - http://www.devmachines.com/

At the moment there are Microsoft Ribbon Control for Qt, DataGrid for Qt, Charting for Qt.
All components are commercial and should be used in Qt Commercial or Qt LGPL.